# How to close app by clicking a button in the notification?

Tags: android

I try to close my app after button click.

I know that i need to use pending intent and intent to do that, but i don't know how can i do it and which flags or actions can I use.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Close your app")
            .setContentText("Your app is still running...")
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_exit,"Close App",
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

This is not working...

Comment: you want to force stop your app or only finish activities

Comment: Closing MainActivity is enough

Comment: then finish your activity only